# php error preg_match Unknown modifier '2'

Tags: php, regex

i not understandy i am getting the error  `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '2'` here is my code i trying to parse the audio format.

```
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @return string|null
 */
public static function parseAudioFormat(string $name): ?string
{
    $Audios = ['AAC', 'AC-3', 'DTS', 'DTS-HD Master Audio', 'DTS-ES', 'DTS 96/24', 'E-AC-3', 'FLAC', 'MP2', 'MP3', 'Opus', 'PCM', 'TrueHD', 'Atmos', 'Vorbis'];
    foreach ($Audios as $audio) {
        if (preg_match("/\b($audio)\b/i", $name, $m)) {
            return $m[0];
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Through the power of substitution :: f($audio)= "/\b($audio)\b/i", f(DTS 96/24)= "`/`\b(DTS 96`/`24)\b`/`i" ,, we see that it is not a metachar problem, but a delimiter problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forward slash needs to be escaped (`'DTS 96/24'`).

You can do it automatically using [preg_quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) :

```
foreach ($Audios as $audio) {
    if (preg_match("/\b(" . preg_quote($audio) . ")\b/i", $name, $m)) {
        return $m[0];
    }

}
```

Comment: The dashes also need to be escaped, but yes, `preg_quote` will do the trick for those too

Comment: @MatthewAnderson not necessary, they are out of character class actually

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using what are called [meta-characters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) in your search strings and must be escaped in order to be used literally.